# mysql join query on null value in the left table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables

### User table

```
user_id   name   location_id  status_id 
1         test   1               1
2         john   NULL            1
3         royi   1               1
4         mahi   2               1
```

### Location table

```
location_id   location_name   location_type  status_id 
1            US                  1               1
2            UK                  1               1
3            BR                  1               1
4            IN                  2               1
```

I want to join the user and location table with location_id and find the null record also.
I have implemented the following query but it won't working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
    left join location l 
        ON u.location_id = l.location_id 
WHERE 
    u.status_id = 1 
    and l.status_id = 1 
    and l.location_type = 1 
    or u.location_id IS NULL
```

I am expecting the result like

```
user_id   name   location_id  status_id location_id   location_name   location_type status_id 
1         test   1               1        1            US                  1               1
2         john   NULL            1        NULL          NULL              NULL             NULL  
3         royi   1               1        1            US                  1               1
4         mahi   2               1        2            UK                  1               1
```

When i change the l.location_type to 2 , the expected result like follows

```
user_id   name   location_id  status_id location_id   location_name   location_type status_id 
2         john   NULL            1        NULL          NULL              NULL             NULL
```

Comment: Can you specify the expected output ? Because when cannot give you a solution without an issue.

Comment: Where is the status_id in USER and LOCATION tables you set the condition on?

Comment: Can you specify the expected output ? Because when cannot give you a solution without an issue. **Which elements in Location table should match with User table in case of NULL ?**

Comment: @Ryx5 i have edited my question.Please look on that

Comment: Not hard, give me 5min I do a sqlfiddle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM user u 
    left join location l 
        ON u.location_id = l.location_id 
        and l.status_id = 1 
        and l.location_type = 1 
where 
    u.status_id = 1
```

[Here is the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/873b5/3)

You don't need to use `u.location_id IS NULL` because left join does not exclude users, it just adds on matched location the location of the user.

I have seen that you edited your post and changed the status_id of john from 2 to 1. Of course if John status id is 2, the query could never retrieve him (remove `where u.status_id = 1` if needed)

Leave me a comment, if the expected output is wrong I'll fix it fastly.

Comment: hi thnx for ur reply..please change the location_type from 1 to 2 it ll produce all records..but i need the records which location_type = 2 and null record

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain to me what do want functionally and technically? "I want to retrieve all users and display the location if it exists else display user with null values instead of location, but only users in status... and location in status..."

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want user with null values instead of location, but only users in status... and location in status 1 and LOCATION_TYPE =2 we need to get row with user "John" only .I just change l.location_type = 1 to l.location_type = 2

Comment: Perhaps you need that : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df8f3/1 pay attention on the schema and datacontent

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this condition `u.status_id`, I guess you want to write `u.status`..

Everything else seems right.. ^^

Comment: I think you can get that result by removing `or u.location_id IS NULL`

Comment: Please take a look on the expected output which is in myquestion

Answer (score 0):

Since in the null records of location_id, the l.status_id and l.location_type will also be null there will be no output with your query.

You should have.

```
SELECT * FROM user u 
left join location l ON u.location_id = l.location_id 
WHERE u.status_id = 1 
and ((l.status_id = 1 and l.location_type = 1) or u.location_id IS NULL)
```

Only when you put them in brackets the OR clause will act properly and show either one of them.

I suggest this should be your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM user u left join location l ON u.location_id = l.location_id
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are using left join means you want all records from user and corresponding records from location table along with not exist records in location with null values, you can try below query:

```
SELECT u.*,l.* 
FROM user u 
left join location l 
ON u.location_id = l.location_id 
WHERE u.status_id = 1 and l.status_id = 1 and (l.location_type = 1 or u.location_id is null);
```